# How to automatically assign different Z-Index Values to multiple elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, foreach

for example i have the markup

```
<div>
     <img src="#" alt=""/>
     <img src="#" alt=""/>
     <img src="#" alt=""/>
<div>
```

I want to select $('div img') and then assign each one a z-index value so the first one is 3, second 2, third 1. Is this simple with jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, see the **[demo here](http://jsbin.com/ucano3/edit)** by clicking on the preview button.

```
var total = $('div img').size();

$('div img').each(function(index){
  $(this).css('z-index', total - index);
});
```

Comment: `$('div img')` is not cached = inefficient slow JavaScript. And it wasn't me who downvoted you so quit moaning.

Comment: @Coronatus: This question was not about **speeding up and optimizing the code of the questioner**, and that is kinda tedious and lastly i did not vote you down either. You could have shown the caching stuff in your own answer if you think questioner was worried about speed.

Answer (score 0):

yep, use each function - http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score -1):

```
i = 3;

$('div img').each(function()
{
    $(this).css('z-index', i);

    i -= 1;
});
```

Comment: `$('div img')` is not cached = inefficient slow JavaScript. You should edit the solution for that.

Comment: It is only called once so there is no need for caching. Get a clue.

Comment: Then you should not suggest the same to others. Try to be a responsible, helper fellow, you are here to help others not just to get reputation points. I hope you read my article on SO tips on tricks on my blog. Thanks

Comment: Sarfraz, please learn what you are talking about before talking. Your answer DOES need caching because the selector is done TWICE, mine does not.